# updating row in SQL table throwing Operand Type Clash error

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I'm running into an error for my update function to a SQL database table. The error is:

```
Error: Operand type clash: text is incompatible with smallint
```

And I have no idea what is wrong there should be no values of type `int` anywhere. All the inputs are strings and the table column type are all text. The update function is this:

```
    public static void UpdateRows(string table, string columnToGet, string columnValueGet, string columnToSet, string columnValueToSet)
{
   try
   {
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString);
   string updateString = "UPDATE " + table + " " + "SET " + columnToSet + "=" + columnValueToSet + " WHERE " + columnToGet + "=" + columnValueGet;
   Console.WriteLine(updateString);

   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connection))
   {
         connection.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + columnToSet, "'" + columnValueToSet + "'");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + columnToGet, "'" + columnValueGet + "'");

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
    }

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    throw;
}
}
```

The console outputs a string like this :

```
UPDATE parentDirectory SET Child1ID=50042 WHERE ParentID=10020
```

And then the error appears. What is wrong? I've tried added "'" characters for the value variables, then I get a different error. I've got my Insert function sort of in the same format somewhere else and it works fine. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name should not be a parameter.  By having the parameter include the column name columnValueToSet gets treated as a number.   PS: this looks like a fishy design.
PPS: it also opens it up to SQL injection.

```
public static void UpdateRows(string table, string columnToGet,
             string columnValueGet, string columnToSet, string columnValueToSet)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Global.connectionString);
        string updateString =
                   "UPDATE " + table + " " +
                   "SET " + columnToSet   + "= @columnValueToSet " + 
                   "WHERE " + columnToGet + "= @columnValueGet;";
        Console.WriteLine(updateString);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnValueToSet", columnValueToSet);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@columnValueGet", SqlDbType.Text).Value= columnValueGet;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
 }
```

EDIT: As GarethD pointed out, the key problem is that parentId is defined as Text and there's no conversion between Text and int (there is between varchar and int, but not Text and int).

Comment: This solution works, but it is worth pointing out that the reason the OP's solution was not working is not to do with adding the column names as parameters, it is because there is no implicit conversion between text/int so `WHERE ParentID = 10020` fails because ParentID is text and 10020 is an INT so SQL does not know how to compare them.

Comment: this solution returns this:
`UPDATE parentDirectory SET Child1ID=@columnValueToSet WHERE ParentID=@columnValueGet
Error: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: and by "fishy design", I cannot seem to find any good resources on how to build a `SqlCommand` string by using form controls like a `textbox`. The examples I've seen are for hardcoded values (I'm not using 'foo'!) For this application, the user is simply writing some values into the boxes and the update function is supposed to find the matching row and update the column's value. I just don't know how to properly execute this.

Comment: @ikathegreat: the fishy part is that the table and columns are usually hard coded, otherwise it can be used to access the whole database.  I've changed my answer, so that it should work now.  I hadn't realized that you were using a TEXT column in the database -- that should only be used with older sql servers where you need to hold a character string that may be longer than 8000 characters.  In this particular case, it looks like the db column should be int, or if it can contain non-ints, then varchar.